# move all files from folder A to B whenever a certain string is present

Tags: bash, awk, grep, xargs, cp

I am trying to move files from folder A to folder B whenever a file contains a certain string:

```
grep -Rli '22/05/2018' ads/ | awk -F  "//" '{print $2}' | xargs cp $0 projection/$1

cp: illegal option -- b
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
   cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
```

how to fix this?

Comment: not sure why `awk` is used.. anyway, if you are using Linux, try `xargs -d'\n' cp -t projection/`

Comment: The question is what is `$0` in your `cp` command. I also do not believe that this is how `xargs` works.

Answer (score 3):

Following may help you here.

```
grep -L -Z -r 'your_string_to_be_checked' . | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} target_directory/
```

***Explanation:***

`grep -L`: Means leave those files which are NOT having that specific string which we are searching for.

`-Z`: means output should have `\0` in file names so space is not being used as delimiter.

`-I{} mv {} new_directory/` means replace `{}` with file names and make it like `mv filename new_directory` and run it to move the files to new place.

I am using `mv` here you could use cp too here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're using awk.

Solution:

```
grep -lir '22/05/2018' ~/ads/* | xargs cp -t $DEST_FOLDER
```

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56903/grep-command-to-find-files-containing-text-string-and-move-them)

Answer (score -1):

Once you have the list of filenames you want to copy you could just use xargs -I:

```
$ cat listOfFileNames | xargs -I{} cp {} $destFolder
```

the `-I` option gives a name to the list of arguments, allowing you to place them wherever you want.

Comment: How is the `listOfFileNames` file obtained?

Comment: Like he does for example: grep -Rli '22/05/2018' ads/ | awk -F  "//" '{print $2}'